# DNG to PNG conversion using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, image-conversion, dng

I have captured a burst of 5 dng images from a Nexus6P for scientific imaging. The pixel intensities from the image will be mapped to my measurement value. For further processing the 5 dng images are averaged to reduce the noise and converted to png. I am using the below code to achieve this

```
convert dng:*.dng -average out.png
```

I would like to know if any processing is being done on the dng image, changing the pixel intensity values while conversion as it would affect my final calibration.

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.3-4, Windows 10

Comment: Color Quantum + HDRI may influence value rounding (the `Q16[-HDRI]` suffix noted on the download page). Outside of that, I believe there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One issue I was worried about was whether the colorspace of the output png image is not linear RGB. If it is sRGB the intensities wouldn't be linear with the pixel values.